# can I use a single thread to execute multiple function without chaining of functions?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a basic question in python threading.

When I saw examples, I understood that the threads needs a function to execute.
can I use a single thread to execute multiple function in a serial way?

If so, any other way other than calling next function from current?

like any way I can pass the 'n' functions i need to execute serially initially itself rather than chaining from each functions?

Comment: By having a wrapper function that takes your 'n' functions, sure. Any reason you *don't* want that approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to execute a list of functions in a single thread:

```
funcs = [
    myfunc1,
    myfunc2,
    # ...
]

def thread_func():
    for f in funcs:
        f(arg1, arg2)
```

Note that the functions must all accept the same set of parameters.

Comment: I am calling thread like this thread = Thread(target=sample,kwargs=v2)

Comment: Was looking if i can complete all my functions with a single thread itself serially. my overall system contain 10 thread, each for each server and each thread need to execute  some fuctions serially. This is what i am looking

Answer (score 1):

obviously yes!

assume you want to get a number and add 5 to it
then you want to add 2 to it and print both **at the sime time**, simply do:

```
def plusfive(num):
    print(num+5)

def plustwo(num):
    print(num+2)
    plusfive(num)

plustwo(34)
```

Comment: tnx for the answer. But I dont want to chain the function, means to make an explicit call from a function to trigger next function

Comment: then you can use a list and make it work using a for loop. as @Jonathon Reinhart mentioned